# Why does this python bs4&csv writer code write in BOM?

Tags: python, csv, web-scraping, utf-8, beautifulsoup

I am extracting a multi-language table from HTML with bs4 and save it as csv. 
But whatever I do with encoding=utf-8, I have the same result of getting a BOM written csv file. 
Is there any easy way to change it using simple options when scraping and saving the HTML?
(I changed utf-8 to euc-** options since the target website is written in multinational languages but it was in vain)

```
soup=bs(res.text,'html.parser',from_encoding='utf8')

    resultset = soup.find('table',class_="type_12345")

    print(resultset)
    records=[]
    for tr in resultset.find_all('tr'):
        tds = tr.find_all('td')
        #url = tds[2].a.get('href')
        records.append([elem.text.encode('utf8') for elem in tds])


    with open('whystillBOM.csv', 'a',encoding="utf-8-sig") as f:
        writer = csv.writer(f)
        writer.writerows(records)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

'utf-8-sig' encoding automatically writes the BOM for Microsoft's version of UTF-8.  If you don't want the BOM, just use UTF-8.

If there's a possibility that the files that you are reading contain a BOM, then you can decode them as utf-8-sig and standard UTF-8 will still be decoded without error.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Even after I changed everything to UTF8 on the code above, it still writes BOM file.. What would be the reason? thanks

Comment: Did you use a new output file?  Just appending to an existing csv will not remove the BOM from the start of the file.  If that's not it, perhaps you could [edit] your question to include some data which produces this result when run through your code (a [mre]).